# MSTest Deployment not working with "../../path" but works with the full path on visual studio 2010

Tags: deployment, mstest, relative-path

I got a problem with MSTest Deployment,
i set folder deployment to something like that **"..\MyProject\bin\debug\"**

I know this path is relative to the test solution dir (C:\dev\MyApplication\Tests in my case) and it appears as
**>Solution Directory>..\MyProject\bin\debug\** in the deployment GUI.

The problem is that there is no error at all but no folder or files are copied.
But if i put the full path like this
**C:\dev\myApplication\MyProject\bin\debug\**
i got a warning that it could not work on other computers as it's outside the solution folder.
despite that warning it works and all files from my debug folder are copied.
The problem is that i want relative pathes as every one on the team got a root path of the solution different of course.
Any Idea ???

I forgot to mention that this project was migrated from VS2008 where it worked to vs2010 where i have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The relativeroot is by default the solution directory. So this should be "MyProject\bin\debug\"